# react-router's browserHistory does not have location and other properties

Tags: react-router

The [docs for history](https://github.com/mjackson/history) which `react-router` links to specify that histories have the following properties:

> - `history.length` - The number of entries in the history stack
> - `history.location` - The current location (see below)?
> - `history.action` - The current navigation action (see below)

But `browserHistory` from react-router does not have these properties. Is this intentional? As far as I can tell the difference is not documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `browserHistory` used by React Router v2/3 uses [history v3](https://github.com/mjackson/history/tree/v3.2.1). The current master branch of history which you link to is v4 and is used by React Router v4.

Comment: Ah, OK. Based on the [changelog](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/CHANGES.md) I thought v3 was the latest version. But I see v4 is in alpha.

Comment: Yes, v4 is a pretty major change. v3 will be maintained, but the push will be towards v4 because it is more React friendly. Things like onEnter and onExit in v3 can just be done in React's lifecycle methods in v4.